# Node view passed data without template engine

Tags: javascript, node.js

Well what i want to do is  to show data from view and edit them.
Example

```
res.render("../modules/users/views/userList", {
            name: 'Adolf'
        });
```

well with handlebars is really simple

```
{{name}}
```

but how can i do this with pure javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ES6 template literals is one way, e.g.:

```
`${name}`
```

Comment: Just dont know why i am getting "name is not defined"
<script type="text/javascript">console.log(`${name}`);</script>